# How can i get last inserted row By using Laravel DB::table()->insert()?

Tags: laravel

I user this code for insert data .

```
$conv = DB::table('conversations')
->insert([
'is_seen' => $other_user_id,
'user_one' => $user_id,
 'user_two' => $other_user_id,
'user_one_status' => 1,
'user_two_status' => 0,
'message_status' => 0,
'last_message' => $messageCon
]);
```

Its return true false value. I need last inserted row.

Comment: [insertGetId](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming there's a reason you're not using Eloquent, you could use insertGetId.

```
$conv = DB::table('conversations')
->insertGetId([
'is_seen' => $other_user_id,
'user_one' => $user_id,
 'user_two' => $other_user_id,
'user_one_status' => 1,
'user_two_status' => 0,
'message_status' => 0,
'last_message' => $messageCon
]);
```

Caveats from the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries):

- Auto-Incrementing IDs
  If the table has an auto-incrementing id, use the insertGetId method to insert a record and then retrieve the ID:
- When using PostgreSQL the insertGetId method expects the auto-incrementing column to be named id. If you would like to retrieve the ID from a different "sequence", you may pass the column name as the second parameter to the insertGetId method.

Answer (score 0):

Insert cant return whole row.
You can change it to `insertGetId` and then select it from database by that id.

Or use models, and use `create` method (`Conversation::create([...])`)